# Two backend servers with Nodemon doesn't reload in docker container when files change

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, nodemon

I am starting my studies with docker, but I faced a problem. I want to run 2 containeirs, where each one will run an express server with nodemon, however the nodemon is not restarting in the container when changes occur in the projects. When running out of the container everything works perfectly.

Project:

[image]

server/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/server

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["npm", "start"];
```

tasks/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/tasks

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"];
```

server/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.15",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

tasks/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tasks",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.15",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  tasks:
    container_name: tasks
    build:
      context: ./tasks
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network

  server:
    container_name: server
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    networks:
      - app-network

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: usubanipal
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: 3241324qwe!
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: rootie
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: asdasd!
    links:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - app-network

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: rootie
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: asdasd!
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /Users/TuTu/COMM/volumes/MongoDB:/data/db
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: The content of a Docker image is fixed once you build it; it doesn't make sense to run a tool like `nodemon` here.  I'd use your working host Node environment for day-to-day development, and set the Docker image to more directly run `CMD ["node", "index.js"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Just add the **volumes** in docker-compose.yml with the correct syntax

```
version: "3"

services:
  tasks:
    container_name: tasks
    build:
      context: ./tasks
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./tasks:/usr/tasks
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network

  server:
    container_name: server
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/server
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    networks:
      - app-network

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: usubanipal
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: 3241324qwe!
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: rootie
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: asdasd!
    links:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - app-network

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: rootie
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: asdasd!
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /Users/TuTu/COMM/volumes/MongoDB:/data/db
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
```